# Iterate through repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

There's this repeater...

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" OnItemCommand="rpt1_ItemCommand" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt1_OnItemDataBound">
     <HeaderTemplate>
         <table width="99%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
             <tr class="lgrey">
                <td>Default</td>
             </tr>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <table>
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" Text="Make Default" CommandName="SetDefault" runat="server" Visible="True" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UserID") %>' CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:Label ID="label1" Text="Yes" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                </td>
             </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
         </table>
     </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

What I want is that when user clicks on any of the "lnk1" link button in the lsit that repeater renders, 
the link should be replaced with the label "label1"..ie when the user clicks on "Make Default" link, it should be replaced 
with "Yes" label

Now when I click 2 link buttons, both get their label "Yes" displayed where as I want only one link button to display Yes 
ie the one which has been clciked and rest of the items should display "Make Default" link button only.

ie Only ONE item should be displaying "Yes" label...now how do I iterate through the repeater items to set only ONE item 
as default and not multiple ??

Comment: I think firstly you need to remove the `table` tag in `ItemTemplate` because you've already got one in `HeaderTemplate`.

Comment: basically you problem is as well as turning on the selected label, you have to go and turn off any labels you turned on before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can iterate the repeater items collection,

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{

    int selectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;
    foreach(RepeaterItem item in myRepeater.Items)
    {
        ((LinkButton)item.FindControl("lnk1")).Visible = (item.ItemIndex != selectedIndex);
        ((Label)item.FindControl("label1")).Visible = (item.ItemIndex == selectedIndex);
    }
}
```

The pros of this option are: 1. no second hit on the database.

Or I would put my logic in the ItemDataBound event instead, store the clicked link button index in a member variable and call DataBind in the command event handler.

```
private int selectedIndex = -1;
//...
protected void myRepeater_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedIndex = e.Item.ItemIndex;

        myRepeater.DataSource = MyGetDataMethod();
        myRepeater.DataBind();        

    }
```

In the ItemDataBound handler compare the current index with the stored index and if they match show the label.

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            if(e.Item.ItemIndex == selectedIndex)
            {
               ((LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnk1")).Visible = false;
               ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("label1")).Visible = true;
            }

        }
    }
```

The cons of this second option are: 1. A second hit on the database. 2. If the user clicks say row two, and some other user inserts a new address record, row 2 may now be something different when you re-bind. Also if you're not using an order by that could change between database calls and your stored selectedIndex could be invalidated thatway too.

So in conclusion I'd go with option one now I've thought it all the way through.

Comment: I implemented like u said..when I clciked on "Make DEfault" Link button..the whole repeater vanished! and debugger won't go inside of repeater's ItemDataBound event...whats wrong ?

Comment: Ok I only added a databind call as I don't know how you are binding your data, Usually I have a method called private void BindAddress() or whatever and in there I set the DateSource and then call DataBind() then whenever I need to rebind I call BindAddress(); So you need to add that bit yourself.

Comment: If you were using an SqlDataSource or ObjectDataSource then just calling DataBind() would work.

Comment: I added the DataSource bit in the ItemCommand handler. The MyGetDataMethod will be however your getting your data LINQ to SQL ADO.NET or whatever.