# If statement in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213594/iterate-through-repeater) repeater on my page..Under the default column what I want is that there
 should be an IF condition that checks my table's "IsDEfault" field value. 
If IsDefault=True then the lable below "label1" ie "Yes" should be
displayed inside the repeater else "Make DEfault" link should be displayed..

Now how do I include this IF statement as inline code in my repeater to accomplish what I want ?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" Text="Make Default" CommandName="SetDefault" runat="server" Visible="True" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UserID") %>' CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>

<asp:Label ID="label1" Text="Yes" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
```

I have an idea :-

```
<%# If DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"IsDefault") = "True"
Then%>
<%End If%>
```

How should I form the "Then" statement now? 
Please help me with the proper syntax..thnx
Do I need to like make a method that checks if "IsDefault" is true or not and  then call it inside of inline code in my repeater ? How do I go about it ?

[EDIT]

I tried as follows:-

```
<% If (Eval("Container.DataItem,"IsDefault"")="True"?

("<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" Text="Set as Default" CommandName="SetDefault1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("User1ID") %>'
CausesValidation="false" Visible=true></asp:LinkButton>") : ("<asp:Label ID="label1" Text="Yes" runat="server" Visible=true></asp:Label>")
)%>
```

didnt work :( Help!!

Comment: why do it inline? your making life more difficult than it has to be. just do it in the itemdatabound event in the code-behind.

Comment: @RPM..How do I do that ? Can u like give example, pseudo code or something ? thnx

Comment: @5arx::I have set this attribute in my repeater OnItemDataBound="rpt1_ItemDataBound"  ...its not working ...plz find my repeater code here :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213594/iterate-through-repeater

Comment: @Serenity: Have a look at this: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/tutorials/article.php/c12065

Comment: @5arx:: I am accessing controls in ItemDataBound Event only..check updated code above..Its not working..All I want to accomplish is that render a lable OR a Link Button inside a repeater based on table record's value ie IsDefault's value...How do u do it if not this way..I am so lost

Comment: I'll take a quick look, if you can you post all your Gui & repeater code ...

Comment: here is the GUI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213594/iterate-through-repeater..repeater's OnItemDataBound event codeis in the ques above...how do I render a control on page based on a value in the record ? Thats all I wanna know...thnx

Comment: @Serenity - I've posted some code below. The only tricky bit is casting e.Item.DataItem to your custom bllusers object. Once you've done that you can check its fields and format as appropriate. 

Hth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your repeater markup. Notice both controls are hidden at the start:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpt1" OnItemDataBound="rpt1_ItemDataBound" onitemcommand="rpt1_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p>
            ID: <%# Eval("Id") %>
            IsDefault: <%# Eval("IsDefault") %>
            Name: <%# Eval("Name") %>

            <asp:Label BackColor="Blue" ForeColor="White" runat="server" ID="lDefault" Text="DEFAULT" Visible="false" />

            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnMakeDefault" Text="Make Default" Visible="false" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
        </p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And some code to go with it. Note I've simulated the retrieval of your collection of blluser objects, so there is some additional code there relating to this which you won't require as, presumably the bllusers collection that you bind to is coming from a db or something?

Anyway I *think* this is what you're looking for, but let me know if its not ;-)

```
 //Dummy object for illustrative purposes only.
[Serializable]
public class bllUsers
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool isDefault { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bllUsers(int _id, bool _isDefault, string _name)
    {
        this.Id = _id;
        this.isDefault = _isDefault;
        this.Name = _name;
    }
}

protected List<bllUsers> lstUsers{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["lstUsers"] == null){
            ViewState["lstUsers"] = buildUserList();
        }
        return (List<bllUsers>)ViewState["lstUsers"];
        }
        set{
            ViewState["lstUsers"] = value;
        }
    }


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        buildGui();
    }
}

private List<bllUsers> buildUserList(){
    lstUsers = new List<bllUsers>();
    lstUsers.Add(new bllUsers(1, false, "Joe Bloggs"));
    lstUsers.Add(new bllUsers(2, true, "Charlie Brown"));
    lstUsers.Add(new bllUsers(3, true, "Barack Obama"));

    return lstUsers;
}

private void buildGui()
{
    rpt1.DataSource = lstUsers;
        rpt1.DataBind();
}

protected void rpt1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        bllUsers obj = (bllUsers)e.Item.DataItem;//this is the actual bllUser the row is being bound to.

        //Set the labels
        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("ldefault")).Visible = obj.isDefault;
        ((Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnMakeDefault")).Visible = ! obj.isDefault;

        //Or use a more readable if/else if you want:
        if (obj.isDefault)
        {
            //show/hide    
        }
        else
        {
            //set visible/invisible
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you want some control to be visible only on some condition, set the Visible property according to that condition:

```
<asp:Label ID="label1" Text="Yes" runat="server" 
    Visible="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"IsDefault") %>" />
```

**EDIT**
If you want the control INvisible for the "IsDefault" situation, reverse the test with something like `Visible="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"IsDefault")==False %>"`.
I'm not quite sure about the exact syntax, but you should get the idea.

Comment: ok I tried that..now what is happening is that...BOTh lable and LinkButton ie "Make Default" link and "Yes" label are getting displayed under repeater col..I want onl one of these 2 to get displayed at a time...How do I check if "IsDefault" = true , display YES label else display that Link button

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say you to be honest i was unable to understand what actually you wanted to do
If your looking to use the condition in the Item Templet then i think
the following systax will help you

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Label1" runat="server"
Text='<%# ((Eval("Cond"))="True" ? Eval("Result for True") : Eval("Result for False") )%>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: for reference, the C# syntax would be like this (for example, conditional style):
 `style='<%# ( Eval("myField").ToString() == "" ? "visibility:hidden;": "" ) %>'`